# How to parse HTML template in GO, Google App Engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine, parsing, templates, go

I'm trying to make a page in GO with Google App Engine which can show the content of an array with HTML parsing.

```
    package hello

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)
}

const TemplateHTML = `
<html>
  <body>
   <table width="700"  border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
    {{range}} {{.name}} {{end}} {{range}} {{.Count}} {{end}}
</td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </body>
</html>
`

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    type variables struct {
        Name    string
        Count   int
    }
    var data = []variables{
        {"John", 25},
        {"George", 35},
        {"NoName", 27},
    }

    //name := variables{"Somebody", 25}
    tmpl, err := template.New("i").Parse(TemplateHTML)

    if err != nil {
         fmt.Fprint(w, err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Fprint(w, err)
    }

}
```

But I only get an *Internal Server Error*.

When I used `err = tmpl.Execute(w, name)` (you can find 'name' in the comment in the code) it was okay.

Do you have any idea what can be the problem? I'm new in golang.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone else will respond with a much more concise/accurate answer, but one simple way you can get your above example to work is to change your `data` declaration to:

```
var data = []variables{
    variables{"John", 25},
    variables{"George", 35},
    variables{"NoName", 27},
}
```

Here, you are making each element of the `data` slice of type `variables`, which will match the `variables` type in the definition. I believe this was the main issue with your current version - the proper data type was not being supplied to `data`. Then, you will just need to adjust your template so that your string looks as follows:

```
const TemplateHTML = `
<html>
  <body>
   <table width="700"  border="1" align="center">
    {{range .}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{.Name}}</td><td>{{.Count}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{end}}
  </tr>
</table>

  </body>
</html>
`
```

The key changes here were: making `.Name` uppercase so it matches the property name and wrapping `tr` in the `{{range .}}` block so that a new row gets created for each entry (I assumed that's what you were looking for - if not, just make sure that `range` encompasses whatever dynamic content you want).

Comment: That's not right. There's no need to say `variables` in a slice literal for `[]variables`. That change has no effect on the compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

If `template.Parse` returns an error, you can't use the other value it returns. You're trying to call `tmpl.Execute` on a nil `tmpl` if the template execution failed, which would lead to a panic.